# How to replace string depending on whether it is odd or even

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I m trying to replace a string "::" on a plain text for <b> or </b>. Depending of the first or second match without result with sed. The goal here is that the second tag </b> can be at the end of a paragraph not at the end of a line. i.e:

```
::Habiéndose calmado de distracciones, uno permanece completamente, 
y la naturaleza superior es vista con los ojos de la sabiduría.::
```

must be

```
<b>Habiéndose calmado de distracciones, uno permanece completamente, 
y la naturaleza superior es vista con los ojos de la sabiduría.</b>
```

I try it without result:

```
sed "s|::\(.*\)|\\<b>\1\</b>|g" EntrenamientoProgresivoSamadhi
```

Comment: This will be much easier with `awk`, since you can increment a counter and check if it's odd or even

Comment: please update the question with more sample inputs (eg, an instance where the trailing `::` is not at the end of a line; can a pair of `::` be on the same line?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `::` can occur more than once on a given line of input
- `::` never shows up as data (ie, we need to replace *all* occurrences of `::`)
- a solution using `awk` is acceptable

Adding some more data to our input:

```
$ cat file
::Habiéndose calmado de distracciones, uno permanece completamente,
y la naturaleza superior es vista con los ojos de la sabiduría.::
some more ::text1:: and then some more ::text2:: the end
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { tag[0]="<b>"; tag[1]="</b>" }
      { while (sub(/::/,tag[c%2])) c++; print }
' file
```

This generates:

```
<b>Habiéndose calmado de distracciones, uno permanece completamente,
y la naturaleza superior es vista con los ojos de la sabiduría.</b>
some more <b>text1</b> and then some more <b>text2</b> the end
```

Comment: Works!! Thank you for the reply and the simplicity and effective method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` and increment a counter variable. Then you can perform a different substitution depending on whether it's odd or event.

```
awk '/::/ && counter++ % 2 == 0 {sub("::", "<b>") }
     /::/ {sub("::", "</b>") }
     1'
```

Note that this will only work correctly if the start and end `::` are on different lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez 's~::(.[^:]*)::~<b>\1</b>~' input_file
<b>Habiéndose calmado de distracciones, uno permanece completamente, 
y la naturaleza superior es vista con los ojos de la sabiduría.</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/::/{x;s/^/x/;/xx/{s///;x;s/::/<\/b>/;ba};x;s/::/<b>/;ba}' file
```

If a line contains `::`, swap to the hold space and increment a counter by inserting an `x` at the start of the line.

If the counter is 2 i.e. the swap space contains `xx`, reset the counter and then swap back to the pattern space and replace `::` by `<\b>` and go again (in the case that a line contains 2 or more `::` strings).

Otherwise, swap back to the pattern space and replace `::` by `<b` and go again (for reasons explained above).

All other lines are untouched.